# WordPress static frontpage and blog page

Tags: php, wordpress

In my theme, i have defined a front-page.php (witch gets loaded when i visit the front page (url root)) and a home.php file for the blog section (posts). I'm a little confused on this, because people are saying different things, and my home.php is loading the front-page.php for some reason?

I've set front page to be an empty page, and the blog section to show another empty page in the reading settings, but still my front-page.php gets loaded on both pages?

How should i do this the correct way when having a static front-page, and want a separate blog page.

Comment: From the setting->reading which page you make as your static home page.?

Comment: Set front-page as static page for home page. And use Custom template page for your blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, below, is a Snapshot of the WordPress Backend depicting how to set the Static Front-Page and the Posts Page (Blogs). You can find the page depicted in this snapshot at: Settings ==> Reading. When done correctly, everything will work normally. In this arbitrary Example, the Front Page corresponds to a Page named: *The Ministry* and the Blogs [Posts] Page corresponds to a Page named: *Christian Blog*.

Creating Physical Files (Templates) wouldn't automatically set the Front Page to any arbitrary Page. If you need a Static Page, this is where you have to explicitly tell WordPress how to handle it. By default, your Front Page is your Latest Posts until you change the Settings here:

[image]

Make Sure, however, that the chosen Pages already exists in the Pages section of your WordPress Backend.

Good Luck.